# Как узнать количество записей, которое вернулось из запроса where?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть следующий `linq` запрос

```
var findInfoKey = dsCr.Items.Where(keyItem => keyItem.CR_ReportID == idProject);
```

Хочу понять сколько записей вернулось. Пытался узнать через метод `Count()`, но выпадает исключение

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Не понимаю в чём проблема. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Версия Entity Framework: 6

***Извиняюсь, я на самом деле не полный запрос написал, посчитав что это не важно, на самом деле запрос выглядел следующим образом:

```
var findInfoKey = dsCr.Items.Where(keyItem => keyItem.CR_ReportID == idProject && keyItem.iv_ID == _item.Element("iv_ID").Value);
```

Вся проблема была в **_item.Element("iv_ID").Value** я так понял, что эти запросы не совместимы, т.е. в запросе LinqToEntity используется LinqToObjects, вроде я правильно понял. Буду благодарен если кто-нибудь пояснит эту ошибку.

Comment: `var findInfoKey = dsCr.Items.Where(keyItem => keyItem.CR_ReportID == idProject).ToList();` а потом `findInfoKey.Count()`

Comment: Вытащите значение `_item.Element("iv_ID").Value` до собственно linq запроса. Потом переменную с этим значением вставьте в запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете метод [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx), никакие записи еще не "возвращаются". Метод Where только строит запрос, для выполнения запроса нужно вызвать материализующий метод.

Например, через [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx). Ваш вариант - вызов [`Queryable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb468851(v=vs.110).aspx) тоже выполняет запрос, но не целиком - а сначала изменяет его так чтобы он вернул только количество записей.

Поэтому то, что вы приняли за ошибку метода Count - на самом деле является ошибкой составления запроса. Конкретно в данном случае библиотека EF не поняла, что выражение `_item.Element("iv_ID").Value` можно вычислить локально и попыталась преобразовать его в SQL. Безуспешно.

Вынесите получение значения XML-элемента в отдельную переменную и сравнивайте уже с ней. Ошибка должна пропасть.

Answer (score 1):

Извлекаем контент в List и считаем

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Document DocObject = context.Document.Find(_id);
    int GroupCount = context.Document.Where(w=>w.Group == DocObject.Group).ToList().Count();
}
```

Прямой запрос к базе без загрузки всего контента:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Document DocObject = context.Document.Find(_id);
    int GroupCount = context.Document.Where(w=>w.Group == DocObject.Group).Count();
}
```

Comment: `context.Document.Count(w=>w.Group == DocObject.Group);`

Comment: @tCode, синтаксический сахар...